# Loop through a range of cells Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

First of all, I'm new to coding - so the script that I have I combined it from a couple different scripts and it seems to work, but I would like to simplify it.

I have such a script:

> function count() {
>
> ```
>   var Month = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Private').getRange('A2').getValues();
>     var PCC = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Private').getRange('B1').getValues();
>     var PCCQ = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(Month).getRange(PCC);
>     var PCCS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(Month).getRange('B4').getValue();
>     var PhoneCC = GmailApp.search(PCCS);
> ```
>
> PCCQ.setValue(PhoneCC.length);

}

What it does:

1. it takes the name of the sheet where I want the results from cell **A2** of sheet Private.
2. it takes the cell where I want the result from cell **B1** of sheet Private.
3. we get the range by combining the sheet name in **1** and cell from **2**
4. it takes the query that we need from the sheet that get from **1** and cell **B4**
5. makes a search in Gmail with the query from **4**
6. sets the value of the cell from point **3** as the length of the search from point **5**

However I have a range of cells for point **2** that I need this to work through, let's say **B1:B70**.

Is there a way to adjust this script to do this?

Will be very thankful.

Answer (score 2):

I'd make the following changes.  Keep going.

```
    var Month = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Private').getRange('A2').getValue();
    var PCC = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Private').getRange('B1').getValue();
    var PCCQ = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Month').getRange(PCC);//The range is not sensible unless it is a named range but the getRange does not work with named ranges.
    var PCCS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Month').getRange('B4').getValue();
    var PhoneCC = GmailApp.search(PCCS); //how do you plan to display your results.
```

Comment: I don't need to display the results, I just need the number of results, that's why I have: 
** PCCQ.setValue(PhoneCC.length); **

Thanks

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice that.  I'd recommend putting all of your code in the code blocks.  We expect it to be there.  Just to let you know getValues returns a two dimensional array even if there is only one element.  getValue returns the contents of the cell.   Two different kinds of things.